# Extend ActonBar header

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to do what GMail for Android does - it displays a number of unread emails in the top right corner of the split ActionBar. Couldn't find anything easy enough to implement with in the documentation, I just want to add a label with a large font in the top corner and update it.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably using `setCustomView()` on `ActionBar`.